# Query to group without lost IF function

Tags: mysql

I created a query to search for all my stock products that are in orders placed, and I created an alias "total_vendido" that adds the products when they are kits or units, so far this is ok. But now I need to group the sizes and add this "total_vendido" alias by size.

Query:

```
SELECT `gp`.`id`, `gp`.`data`, `gp`.`status`, `gp`.`situacao`, `gp`.`nome`, 
 `gp`.`razao_social`, `gp`.`email`, `gp`.`telefone`,
 `itens`.*, 
 IF(itens.tipo = 'K', 
   SUM(itens.qtde_prod) * itens.qtde_lote, 
   SUM(itens.qtde_prod)
 ) AS total_vendido,
 `estoq`.`titulo` 
FROM `ga845_pedidos_view` `gp` 
JOIN `ga845_pedido_itens` `itens` ON `itens`.`pedido_id` = `gp`.`id` 
JOIN `ga845_produtos` `prod` ON `prod`.`id` = `itens`.`produtos_id` 
JOIN `ga845_produtos_estoque` `estoq` ON `estoq`.`id` = `prod`.`estoques_id` 
WHERE `gp`.`situacao` IN('Pedido Realizado', 'Pagamento Aprovado', 
  'Pedido em Separação', 'Pedido Separado') 
 AND date(gp.data) >= '2020-07-25' 
 AND date(gp.data) <= '2020-07-25' 
 AND `estoq`.`id` IN('24') 
GROUP BY `itens`.`tamanho_prod`, `estoq`.`id` 
ORDER BY `estoq`.`id` ASC, `itens`.`tamanho_prod` ASC
```

Current result (only important columns)

```
tamanho_prod | tipo | total_vendido
G            | K    | 5
G            | U    | 1
M            | K    | 1
P            | U    | 8
```

Expected result (only important columns)

```
tamanho_prod | total_vendido
G            | 6
M            | 1
P            | 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Code related to Expected result (only important columns)

```
    SELECT 
    , `itens`.`tamanho_prod`
    ,  SUM( IF(itens.tipo = 'K', 
        itens.qtde_prod  * itens.qtde_lote, 
        itens.qtde_prod 
     ) AS total_vendido
    FROM `ga845_pedidos_view` `gp` 
    JOIN `ga845_pedido_itens` `itens` ON `itens`.`pedido_id` = `gp`.`id` 
    JOIN `ga845_produtos` `prod` ON `prod`.`id` = `itens`.`produtos_id` 
    JOIN `ga845_produtos_estoque` `estoq` ON `estoq`.`id` = `prod`.`estoques_id` 
    WHERE `gp`.`situacao` IN('Pedido Realizado', 'Pagamento Aprovado', 
      'Pedido em Separação', 'Pedido Separado') 
     AND date(gp.data) >= '2020-07-25' 
     AND date(gp.data) <= '2020-07-25' 
     AND `estoq`.`id` IN('24') 
    GROUP BY `itens`.`tamanho_prod`
    ORDER BY `itens`.`tamanho_prod` ASC
```

if you want an aggregated  result just for `itens.tamanho_prod`  .. then you should  use group by  only for this column ...  and move the SUM() outside the if condition